# Integral of the floor function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

I need to prove “Let $f(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor$. Prove that $f$ is integrable on $[-1,1]$ and find it's integral.”

But I keep getting lost and confused and I’m not sure which approach i should follow through with, whether its breaking up the function into a piece wise function, proving $U(f,P) = L(f,P)$ or $U(f,P)-L(f,P) < \epsilon$.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

First things first let's write out $f$ on $[0,1]$ very explicitly. That is

$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
-1, & \text{if $x<0$} \\
0, & \text{if $0\leq x<1$} \\
1, & \text{if $x=1$}
\end{cases}
$$

I can see how the last case could cause you some confusion. Fortunately, if you remember the definition of a Riemann sum of a tagged partition, you can see that the contribution of this last case will become small as you create finer partitions, leaving you with something relatively simple.

I'm not gonna give a fully detailed solution since this seems like a homework problem, but this should get you on the right track.